# In the React, is the Route and Container 1: 1?

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, containers

I think need your help.
Currently I am working with React.
I think in React, Container and Route are 1: 1. So when I do Router configuration with React. In a typical 'Redux' configuration, the Container(smart component) same to the number of pages in the route.
If I look at the implementation pattern of others, the Container does not just reflect the route.
Common There are many more cases than Route.

In the structure using 'Redux', is Container 1: 1 Route?
Also, Container does not seem to have an HTML Tag, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not necessarily true, you may have a route that renders a component that doesn't have behaviour and because of that it'd still be a presentational component.

I'd recommend you to not get overwhelmed by the definitions of containers and component. Try to think a Route as just another component with the difference that when the `path` matches it will render the specified component (or in line function if you used the `render` property of the route.

Always start simple by creating components that are just functions which return content, and then as the requirements are changing start growing by declaring a class which extends Component and then start decoupling the returned elements into other components. Same thing with Redux, by default don't assume you always need behaviour/state so don't even connect the component and then start growing by adding state and then adding actions. But whenever you think your component has many responsibilities start the cycle again by decoupling into more components.

Comment: Did it answer your question ? Is there anything else you'd like me to add?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer it it helped you?